# (Excel VBA Formulas) Nested IF Highlighted Red

Tags: excel, vba, formula, nested-if

I have a formula that works in the cell, but it is a really long nested if. It is essentially trying to check a cell for multiple different values.

A2 = This is my description.
B2 contains the nested if, which searches the A2 description for multiple words. As it runs through each if statement, it will print the word that is found.

I need to use VBA to set this formula to multiple cells, but I am not sure why the formula is wrong. (Excel highlights it red.) Is there a better way to write this?

(I've been doing two nested if's on a line, and using " & _" to separate to the next line down.)

```
Sub Search_For_Keywords()
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

    Range(B2).Activate
    With ActiveCell
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Keyword1 "",A2,1)),""1"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Keyword2 "",A2,1)),""2"", & _
```

... there are 48 keywords, and more may need to be added in the future ...

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Keyword_n"",A2,1)),""n"",""No Keywords Found"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"

    End With
Loop
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Another solution (workaround?) is using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E2:E6,MATCH(D2:D6,A2:A6,0)),"Not Found")

=INDEX (column to return a value from, MATCH (lookup value/column, column to lookup against, 0))
```

So for mine, I had D2:D6 containing the keywords to search for, E2:E6 containing each keyword's alias, and then A2:A6 held the actual descriptions I wanted to try and see if the keywords were in.

This code is now short enough to be put in VBA, the only downside being you do have to have columns containing this information.

Thanks again for all the help. Other more VBA specific solutions can be found below.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] (perhaps with fewer keywords). The fact that you just give a fragment of your statement makes it hard to debug.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a double quotation mark after `_` in new line?

Comment: I think so... let me post something else above, that may be easier if we can find a way to tweak it.

Comment: If you can VBA, why not write a decent function with a more readable `Select Case` statment ?

Comment: Hi TSion.D.P. - I have written some, but I would say I am still beginner. Would you have some links or more info on select case? I would definitely give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use VBA you could use this simple code assuming that u just want the word found

```
arr = Array("keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3") 'List of keywords to look for
For i = 0 To 2
    Set c = Sheets(1).Range("a2").Find(arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then Sheets(1).Range("b2").Value = arr(i)  'Setting the value if the keyword is found
Next i
```

But if multiple words are found it will print only the last one (u can modify the code in case u need that). Of course because this is not a calculation you would need to run the code each time the cell value changes

Specific Solution:

```
Sub Find_Keywords()

Keywords = Array("Awesome", "hey", "world") 'List of keywords to look for

Range("A2").Activate

    Do Until ActiveCell = Range("a14")

        For i = 0 To 2
            Set C = ActiveCell.Find(Keywords(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not C Is Nothing Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Keywords(i) 'Setting the value if the keyword is found
        Next i

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Raunak Thomas! This may actually be perfect- my only question being, can the range it is searching be set to the activecell? I tried making it Activecell.Find(arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues) however that did not work.(I ask because I would need to check a lot of cells and I was going to use a do loop with and Activecell.offset for that.)

Comment: active does work, I just tried it. change sheets(1).range("b2") to sheets("your_sheet_name").range("b2") and try.

Comment: Raunak Thomas, thank you so so much! With a few tweaks, I got it to work exactly how I wanted! :) (I updated your comment with my specific solution code, but it has to be peer reviewed before it will show up. I will mark it as an answer.)

Comment: The edit that you suggested will result in an infinite loop, you will have to keep some criteria for the loop to end

Comment: I apologize. I had some cells below that were filled in (related to other parts of the sheet) that would stop it upon activecell <> "". Thank you for catching that. One last question- say I am searching for "Hello" but sometimes the cell says "Helo"- is there any way to output an alias of "Hello" for the "Helo" cell?

Comment: Well a simple solution is to just change the if statement, something like 

If Not C Is Nothing and Keywords(i) = "helo" then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Hello"
elseif Not C Is Nothing then 
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Keywords(i)
end if

If there are many aliases then I would maybe simply create 2 arrays

Answer (score 1):

```
Function SearchMyKeywords(rng As Range)
   Select Case rng
       Case _1st_keyword
            SearchMyKeywords = Whatever_You_Like
       Case _2nd_keyword
            SearchMyKeywords = Whatever_You_Like2
       ...
       Case Else ' For all the rest  
            SearchMyKeywords = Whatever_suitable_here
   End Select
```

Then you can use your function like built in functions

Comment: Hi TSion.D.P. Thank you for posting this. I will do some more reading on Select Case and play around with your code. I think it could prove a good solution as well! I appreciate your help :)